# Java SDK of Stack Overflow for integrating my application

Tags: support, integration

I'm developing a connector to integrate with Stack Overflow. So, is there any Java SDK available for Stack Overflow so that I can integrate it with my connector?

Comment: Does "connector" refer to [JCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Connectors) (Java-specific)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The main question is whether they're still working... We have a [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) which covers the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) and the (unofficial, community-supported) SDKs you're looking for should be [tagged with [library] and [java]](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/java+library).

I have tried none of them; some may be very old and not working with the current version of the API. I have a couple of backend scripts running on Java, but I'm using good old [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html); it's quite easy to generate the right calls with help from the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/). The only caveat is that the response is always [compressed](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression) so you'll need [`GZIPInputStream`](https://stackapps.com/a/6424/34061).