# Question based on Authentication

Tags: support, api, authentication

I am creating a connector which will integrate with the Stack Overflow API. I need to generate an access token of Stack Overflow account so that I can fetch its API. But when I am generating an access token through [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info), it is asking for user approval, but I don't need it.

Is there a way to generate a token using Postman without user approval?

Comment: Related: *[Java SDK of Stack Overflow for integrating my application](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382365/)*

Comment: Is it from some school or university course or tutorial? What is the origin of this?

Answer (score 5):

> But when I am generating an access token through Postman, it is asking for user approval, but I don't need it.

You do need it; an access token identifies the user. Without an approval step, I could make an access token for your account and read your inbox or post questions in your name.

If you don't *need* access to private information and no write access, you don't need an access token to get increased quota; an application key is sufficient. For that, you only need to register your application; [here](https://stackapps.com/q/8971/34061) is a simple guide for that.